# slider revolution Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: plugins, php

I transfer my domain to another hosting and now my website slider revolution wont load .and gives me an error of :

include(/home/u125141493/domains/petmarketers.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/navigations.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/navigation.class.php:254

include(): Failed opening '/home/u125141493/domains/petmarketers.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/navigations.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php80/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php80/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/navigation.class.php:254

please help me with these. I have a hard time fixing it. Thankyou.

Comment: Welcome! Questions about third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here however. The developers of this plugin know it best, and will be able to give you the best support about your problem, I'd recommend you check with their official support routes, or refer to their documentation.